# why php allow to overwriting private method?

Tags: php, overriding, private

In the documentation is this example and understand it without problems

```
class Bar{
    public function test() {
        $this->testPrivate();
        $this->testPublic();
    }
    public function testPublic() {
        echo "Bar::testPublic\n";
    }
    private function testPrivate() {
        echo "Bar::testPrivate\n";
    }
}
class Foo extends Bar{
    public function testPublic() {
        echo "Foo::testPublic\n";
    }
    private function testPrivate() {
        echo "Foo::testPrivate\n";
    }
}

$myFoo = new foo();
$myFoo->test();
```

The result is:

- Bar::testPrivate
- Foo::testPublic

But now redefine the test () method in the class foo

```
 class Bar{
    public function test() {
        echo '<br>Im Bar::test';
        $this->testPrivate();
        $this->testPublic();
    }
    public function testPublic() {
        echo "<br>Bar::testPublic\n";
    }
    private function testPrivate() {
        echo "<br>Bar::testPrivate\n";
    }
}
class Foo extends Bar{
    public function test() {
        echo '<br>Im Foo::test';
        $this->testPrivate();
        $this->testPublic();
    }
    public function testPublic() {
        echo "<br>Foo::testPublic\n";
    }
    private function testPrivate() {
        echo "<br>Foo::testPrivate\n";
    }
}
$myFoo = new Foo();
$myFoo->test();
```

The result is:

- Im Foo::test
- Foo::testPrivate
- Foo::testPublic

php allows me to override the private method testPrivate (), Why?

Answer (score 1):

Why not? It's difficult to answer that question as it's just how PHP works. If you want to prohibit your methods from being overwritten then you can use the `final` keyword.

Additionally, in your example, if you do not declare the private method within Foo, you will get an error as Foo technically has no definition for that method. **Extending classes have no visibility of any private properties or methods within their parent class.**

Comment: but the documentation says `Members declared as private may only be accessed by the class that defines the member.`

Comment: also redefines the private function only if I redefine the test method

Comment: In your example, you are calling `Foo::test();`. When you call a method using `$this`, it will attempt to call methods within it's own definition falling back to the parent if it has no definition. In your example, you have essentially created a new class (`Foo`) because you have overwritten all methods. `Foo::test` is calling `Foo::testPrivate` and `Foo::testPublic`

Comment: If you want to call a method that is defined in the parent of an extended class, use `parent::{method}()` - eg. `parent::testPrivate()`

Comment: I get it, then the visibility does not mean that you can no longer override a private method in a child class. thank you very much